# scanear codigo qr no da informacion

Tags: flutter

estaba haciendo una aplicación que escanea código `QR` y se supone que en la consola me debería dar la información de lo que escaneo,estoy usando un complemento para `flutter` llamado `barcode scanner` eh probado con la mayoría de las versiones,eh probado migrar el código de proyecto ,y probar distintas maneras de emplear la función que recibe la información del código leído,pero solo abre la `app` y me muestra la información de la cámara en la consola,si alguno sabe como solucionarlo seria de mucha ayuda,ya que estoy atascado hace bastante...adjunto el código de la función y foto

```
 `scanQR() async {
         dynamic futureString ='';
         try {
          futureString = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
        }catch(e){
          futureString=e.toString();
        }
       print('Future String: ${futureString.rawContent}');}`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7pIe.jpg)

como ven solo muestra la información de la cámara ,y aunque escanee como 3 códigos `QR no me mostró la información de ninguno,espero que la forma en la que explique haya sido suficiente para que alguno pueda entender y explicarme si es que hago mal

Comment: agrega más log al entrar al método de scaneo, al entrar a la excepción y al salir

Comment: alguien prodria recomendarme algo mas especifico?

Comment: no hay suficiente info como para darte algo específico